# Sharing reference from a mutable method

Tags: rust

Rust does not allow borrowing multiple mutable references. I understand that. But I can not find any elegant way to implement a few algorithms. Below is a simplified version of one such algorithm. The `Ladder` struct hands out slices of ever increasing sequence of numbers, such as, `[0]`, `[0, 1]`, `[0, 1, 2]` and so on.

```rust
struct Ladder {
    position: usize,
    data: [u8; 10],
}

impl Ladder {
    fn get_next(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        self.position += 1;

        &(self.data[0..self.position])
    }
    
    fn new() -> Ladder {
        Ladder {
            position: 0,
            data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        }
    }
}
```

I need to call `get_next()` a couple of times, collect the returned sequences and call a closure that will do something with those sequences.

```rust
fn test_ladder(consumer: impl Fn(&[&[u8]])) {
    let mut l = Ladder::new();
    let mut steps: [&[u8]; 3] = [&[]; 3];

    steps[0] = l.get_next();
    steps[1] = l.get_next();
    steps[2] = l.get_next();

    consumer(&steps);
}

fn main() {
    test_ladder(|steps| {
        for seq in steps {
            println!("{:?}", *seq);
        }
    });
}
```

It is a non-allocating algorithm. I can not use `std::Vec`.

What is the idiomatic way to approach problems like this?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with these ladders? The answer to the code I can see right now is "no, Rust won't let you do that; it's unsafe by the rules of the borrow checker". Can you explain a bit more your objective? I'm guessing that there's a more idiomatic way to represent what you're trying to do in this language.

Comment: Seems like you just need a separate iterator type instead of combining the data and sequencing together.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I have added more code to show what is actually done with the collected sequences. This simplified code does a good job representing what I need to do in my actual work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't keep references to something that you mutate, and `.get_next()` is allowed to mutate `data`. What you need to do is separate the data from the mutation. You can do that by only keeping a reference to the original data.

Creating a sequence of elements sounds a lot like an iterator, so here's an example:

```
struct LadderIter<'a> {
    position: usize,
    data: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> LadderIter<'a> {
    fn new(data: &'a [u8]) -> LadderIter<'a> {
        LadderIter { position: 0, data }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for LadderIter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a [u8];
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.position == self.data.len() {
            None
        } else {
            self.position += 1;
            Some(&self.data[0..self.position])
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can then use as an iterator:

```
for step in LadderIter::new(&[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) {
    println!("{step:?}");
}
```

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or in your specific use-case:

```
let data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let mut ladder = LadderIter::new(&data);
let steps: [&[u8]; 3] = [
    ladder.next().unwrap(),
    ladder.next().unwrap(),
    ladder.next().unwrap(),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use interior mutability. Since you are only modifying `position`, you can use the zero-cost [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html):

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Ladder {
    position: Cell<usize>,
    data: [u8; 10],
}

impl Ladder {
    fn get_next(&self) -> &[u8] {
        self.position.set(self.position.get() + 1);

        &self.data[0..self.position.get()]
    }
    
    fn new() -> Ladder {
        Ladder {
            position: Cell::new(0),
            data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        }
    }
}
```